# Integration of Hortonworks HDP with Mesos

Tags: hadoop, mesos, hortonworks-data-platform, dcos, bigdata

I have to integrate HDP with Mesos. I don't want to do it with cloudbreak, because it's not a mature project. Is there any other ways you can integrate HDP with Mesos ?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrating with HDP"? HDP is a suite of products, isn't it? What exactly would you like Mesos to manage for HDP?

Answer (score 0):

See Apache Myriad (incubating) at http://myriad.incubator.apache.org/